# Android add contact then ContentResolver.requestSync() SyncStatusObserver: sync finished is not called

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I'm  rather new to editing contacts. I want to know when processing (sync / aggregation) of added contacts finished. I'm adding contacts via `ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert`.

I thought I can use `SyncStatusObserver`, and implemented both versions (one, then second) from post [Android - how to get notified when sync finishes, when requesting a sync with ContentResolver.requestSync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227429/android-how-to-get-notified-when-sync-finishes-when-requesting-a-sync-with-co).

However, MySyncStatusObserver `onStatusChanged` / `onSyncsFinished` are not called when I insert contact to google account which has sync contacts `ON` setting. They are not called later when I run `ContentResolver.requestSync`. They are not called when I manually add contact in Android to google account.
The SyncStatusObserver was called once when I manually set sync option to `off` then `on`.

By the way, `ContentResolver.requestSync(account, "the sync authority", null);` from post produce null exception, I changed `null` to

```
Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
```

What am I missing? How can I find out when sync / aggregation finished after adding contact? My main goal now is to wait until WhatsApp account gets all contacts from inserted.