# get notified when requestSync function completed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

im trying to start the calendar sync programatically using this code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_IGNORE_SETTINGS, true);

ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], "com.android.calendar", bundle);
```

i want a way so i can know when sync complete so i can read data from the calendar
i tried doing this

```
while (ContentResolver.isSyncActive(accounts[0], "com.android.calendar")) {
System.out.println("looping: " + i);
}

readLocalCalendar();
readLocalEvents();
```

but the system exit the loop before the sync ends and i can still see the sync sign at the status bar, so any help so i can read calendar events after sync completle done ??

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option would be to register a broadcast receiver to tell you when the sync is finished like this:

```
public class UpdateableActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String ACTION_FINISHED_SYNC = "your.package.ACTION_FINISHED_SYNC";

    private static IntentFilter syncIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISHED_SYNC);

    private BroadcastReceiver syncBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // update your views
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register for sync
        registerReceiver(syncBroadcastReceiver, syncIntentFilter);
        // do your resuming magic
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(syncBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Inside your SyncAdapter use this when done:

```
getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(UpdateableActivity.ACTION_FINISHED_SYNC));
```

You can also use this for when starting or updating the status of the sync ;)

**Update:** Updated the code to avoid leaks and making sure the activity is still active (onResume/onPause)

Answer (score 1):

using the [addStatusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addStatusChangeListener%28int,%20android.content.SyncStatusObserver%29) actually worked for me .

[here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657333/878126) a reference .

don't forget to add the needed permissions .

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener (int mask, SyncStatusObserver callback)` to get notified of changes in sync status. [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addStatusChangeListener%28int,%20android.content.SyncStatusObserver%29)

Please do not loop forever, its really bad design. Using the above method everything is asynchronous so you don't waste any cpu cycles.

You could also use `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver (Uri uri, boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) to get notified in changes on a specific URI (like the calendar's URI)

Comment: thank you , but i tried the SyncStatusObserver , but i faced a problem, because these two methods "readLocalCalendar();
readLocalEvents()" have effects on the interface , so an exception is fired saying that i cant modfy the view from another thread !!  this is the exception  (E/JavaBinder(12336): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.)

Answer (score -3):

try an AsyncTask :

```
private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO sync your calendar
      }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
        //TODO display a spinner or something else to show progress
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Void t){
       //TODO what you want when doInBackground has finished

      }

}
```

Good luck !