# onStatusChanged() in SyncStatusObserver called multiple times

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my app I need to show upcoming event from Google Calendar. I've done it with [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html). To track new events (those added in web version of Google Calendar), I decided to request sync of calendar, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657333/1178797).

It works well, but I noticed that onStatusChanged(int) method called multiple times. Following code

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(int which) {
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] acc = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if (acc.length > 0) {
        account = acc[0];
        boolean syncActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(
                account, CalendarContract.AUTHORITY);
        Log.d(TAG, "sync done = " + !syncActive);

        // is it right to update view here depending on syncActive value?

    }
}
```

Gives me output like this:

```
03-26 13:11:19.650  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = false
03-26 13:11:20.919  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = true
03-26 13:11:20.924  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = false
03-26 13:11:21.651  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = true
03-26 13:11:21.656  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = false
03-26 13:11:22.253  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = true
03-26 13:11:22.256  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = false
03-26 13:11:22.761  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = true
03-26 13:11:22.777  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = false
03-26 13:11:23.359  D/EventsActivity﹕ sync done = true
```

How observer is registered:

```
mContentProviderHandle = ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(
        ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_ACTIVE, this);
```

I wanted to update my views where I placed the comment in the first piece of code, but it's obvious that my views will be updated multiple times. What am I missing?

Comment: if your code inside the listener is changing the state then you should unregister the listener and re-register it later

Comment: @abdelrahman-elkady, my onStatusChanged() looks exactly like in the question. Or do you mean ContentResolver.isSyncActive() changes the state?

Comment: It seems it doesn't change the state .. I don't know actually thought there is more code there !